# How do i click this button in capybara (using 'ID' or 'Xpath' selector)

Tags: ruby, testing, automation, cucumber, capybara

Please help me solve this problem

I have a button like in Capybara:

```
<li id="main-menu-button" data-radium="true" style="flex: 0 0 auto; padding:   0px; box-sizing: border-box; color: rgb(158, 144, 212); display: flex; margin: 5px; border-radius: 5px; width: 50px; height: 50px; flex-flow: row nowrap; justify-content: center; position: relative; transition: background-color 100ms ease-out;">
  <img src="/assets/images/branding/reachify-r-logo-white.png" alt="Logo" data-radium="true" style="width: 50px; height: 50px; padding: 10px; box-sizing: border-box; border-radius: 4px; background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);">
</li>
```

I tried with:
click_button "main-menu-button"
and
find_button("main-menu-button").click

but it gives error:

```
 Unable to find button "Organization" 
  (Capybara::ElementNotFound)
```

Comment: ca you show the html for the button?

Comment: <li id="main-menu-button" data-radium="true" style="flex: 0 0 auto; padding:   0px; box-sizing: border-box; color: rgb(158, 144, 212); display: flex; margin: 5px; border-radius: 5px; width: 50px; height: 50px; flex-flow: row nowrap; justify-content: center; position: relative; transition: background-color 100ms ease-out;">
  <img src="/assets/images/branding/reachify-r-logo-white.png" alt="Logo" data-radium="true" style="width: 50px; height: 50px; padding: 10px; box-sizing: border-box; border-radius: 4px; background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);">
</li>

Answer (score 12):

It's not a button (or input type=button) element so click_button and find_button aren't going to work.  You just need to do

```
find('#main-menu-button').click
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. It shows when i do this:                                         Unable to find css "#main-menu-button" (Capybara::ElementNotFound)
      ./features/step_definitions/login.rb:18:in `/^I click Organization button$/'
      features/login.feature:8:in `And I click Organization button'

Comment: @ArturAbdullin Then the thing you're trying to click either doesn't have the id of your example button (main-menu-button), isn't in the page at all, or isn't visible on the page, since it's an li element, is that part of a dropdown or something that you need to click on something else first or hover over something else first before it becomes visible?

Comment: This is a button element. [Screen Shot 2016-10-28 at 3.26.42 PM.png](https://postimg.org/image/n3vewg2hx/)

Comment: @ArturAbdullin  You asked how to click on the <li> element you posted in the question.  That is not a <button> element.  If that's not what you want to click on then you need to provide the actual HTML you want to click on, and or details on what the user has to do to make that element visible on the page.